# Repast4py random walk example wit RDMAV_FORK_SAFE error

Tags: mpi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, repast4py

I run the randomwalk example, but it showed the RDMAV_FORK_SAFE error, "A process has executed an operation involving a call to the fork() system call to create a child process."
someone could helps, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but setting the environment variable RDMAV_FORK_SAFE to 1:

```
export RDMAV_FORK_SAFE=1
```

will prevent the error.